# sub-netting for 62 hosts only gives me 3 usable networks?

Tags: subnet

I use the following table to workout the required subnet mask for my network of 62 hosts which is `255.255.255.192` which according to the table gives me 4 use-able networks.

[image: subnetting table]

In this case the first network address is `192.168.1.64` with a range of 65-126 and broadcast of 127.

second network: 192.168.1.128, range=129-190, broadcast=191.

third network: 192.168.1.192, range=193-254, broadcast=255.

But I don't understand the fourth network. If the table is correct it should start with `192.168.1.256` is this correct? In which case what would the range and broadcast be for this fourth network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

192.168.1.0 with a range of 1-62  and broadcast of .63 is the block you missed.